# Text Extraction from xlsx file having multiple sheets based on given sheet name using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, text-extraction

I have an xlsx file which contains around 150 sheets in it. I need to extract text for only 30 of those sheets, I have tried the below code but this extracts the text for all of the sheets.

```
            try (InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
            OPCPackage d=OPCPackage.open(inp);
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(d);
            XSSFExcelExtractor extractor = new XSSFExcelExtractor(wb);
            extractor.setFormulasNotResults(true);
            extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(false);
            String text = extractor.getText().replaceAll("\\t"," ").replaceAll("%","");
            lines =text.split("\n");
```

Could someone please help me if there is any method available using which I can extract text by giving the sheet names for which I want to extract data.

Comment: Don't use the extractor. Instead get the cell contents of the sheets you wants using the [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) approach. 

Or take a look [what exactly the extractor is doing](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_1_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFExcelExtractor.java?view=markup). Then do programming your own extractor which fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Thank you will give a try to second approach you mentioned looks like that would be best my for scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure

Class `Workbook` has method `getSheet(String name)` that returns `Sheet` instance.
I don't remember correct class name but you can write something like this

```
List<String> sheetNames = List.of("sheet1", "sheet2", .... );
List<Sheet> sheets = new ArrayList<>();
sheetNames.forEach(nm -> sheets.add(workbook.getSheet(nm)));
```

then you may want to filter out nulls (when sheet wasn't found)

```
sheets = sheets.stream().filter(s -> Objects.notNull(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

here you go

Comment: I am able to get the required sheets using it but XSSFExcelExtractor method is accepting workbook type argument only. I need to extract text for the selected sheets now one by one.